# SAS basic analysis problems

Tags: statistics, sas

first time SAS user here.

I have a dataset (plant) imported to SAS where I changed two variables from numeric to categorical. I managed to fit my model like so:

```
proc glm data=plant_formatted;
    class dose_factor greenhouse_factor;
    model growth = dose_factor light_intensity greenhouse_factor;
run;
```

How do I now find the parameter estimates, 95% confidence intervals and the VIF?

I tried asking chatgpt but it's unfortunately not helping me any further along.

Comment: Add solution to the model statement. `model growth = dose_factor ... / solution;` Not sure about VIF.

Comment: thanks so much Reeza! I also figured out how to get the confidence intervals so now it's just the VIF that I'm stuck with

Comment: ChatGPT is not a reliable source for help. To my knowledge the only SAS PROC that provides VIF out of the box is `PROC REG` with the `/ vif` option in the `model` statement. The problem here is that `PROC REG` doesn't support a `class` statement so you'll have to dummy-code your predictors manually. The other option is to calculate the VIF manually, by regressing each of your predictors onto the others in turn. The latter is quite a bit more work so I'd look into e.g. the procedures `GLMMOD`, `TRANSREG`, or just a simple data step for getting your predictors dummy-coded.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get VIF from `proc reg` with the `vif` model option, but you can get the tolerance from `proc glm`. Type II Tolerance is exactly 1/VIF. By simply taking the inverse of tolerance, you get VIF. Example:

```
proc glm data=sashelp.cars;
    model msrp = horsepower cylinders mpg_city / tolerance;
run;

proc reg data=sashelp.cars;
    model msrp = horsepower cylinders mpg_city / vif;
run;
```

| Variable | Type II Tolerance | VIF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Horsepower | 0.3151489991 | 3.17310 |
| Cylinders | 0.3093127956 | 3.23297 |
| MPG_City | 0.4879345912 | 2.04946 |